# Trouble understanding Spread operator used with Recursive Function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I came across this piece of code(for flattening an object), and I'm having hard time understanding the working of spread operator with recursive function call. I don't understand what spread operator in  `...flatten(value)` is exactly doing. Is it spreading the return value of flatten() function which is res? If yes, then wouldn't it become `res={...res, ...res}` in line 5?

Perhaps a silly question, but I'm confused.

```
const flatten = (obj) => {

  let res = {};

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      res = { ...res, ...flatten(value) };
      console.log(flatten(value));
    } else {
      res[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return res;
};
```

Comment: It's not the same in-scope `res`. It's the return value of a recursive call to flatten an object contained within `obj`. Yes, the variable in the recursive call is also called `res` but it's a different variable, in a different scope.

Comment: I still don't understand, you're saying the two res are different? If they are doesn't it mean that the parent and recursive function(both of which are same) are different? I'm confused really.

Comment: Every time `flatten() is called`, whether that be your initial call or any subsequent recursive call, a new variable named `res` is created and it's only visible within the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of that call. For an initial call and 5 recursive calls, there are 6 `res` variables, all with different block scopes. It's somewhat like Russian dolls.

Comment: That'd make each call have two res right? I mean, on second call, it'd start from the res={} and then later work it's away till res[x]=y? Perhaps it's a bit silly, but I'm confused.  Any source which explains a similar problem pls?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "each call have two res". The original `obj` object can be hierarchical (it's an object that can contain objects that can contain objects ...). The function is called recursively to deal with each level of that object hierarchy. The code accumulates all the object's attributes at a given level and below in `res` and returns that `res` to its parent where it's spread (by the ... spread syntax). I'd propose that you run this code on a few examples and either debug it or print out the values of `res`, `key`, and `value` as it recurses.

Comment: I tried debugging but still can't understand. Suppose I have an object ={a:10,b:{c:20}}, which I pass as an object to the flatten function. In the first iteration, res would be a:10, in the second iteration, owing to b being an object, and recursive call, res would be c:20. What I don't understand is, where does the a:10 go? And also, what's the difference between ...res and ...flatten(value), when the return of flatten(value) is res as well? What is being spreaded with ...res and what is being spreaded with ...flatten(value).

Comment: The outermost scope's res is not a:10 in that case, it's `{a:10}`, and `flatten(value)` is `{c:20}`. Both are objects. Both objects are then spread by `{...res, ...flatten(value)}`. The spread syntax enumerates the properties of an object and adds the key-value pairs to the object being created, resulting in `{a:10, c:20}`.